# Find $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $F\cong\mathbb Q[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$. Find a polynomial
    $f(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ such that $F\cong\mathbb Q[x]/\langle
    f(x)\rangle$, and find a basis for $F$ considered as a vector
    field over $\mathbb Q$.
I'm not sure how to approach this. One or the other used would be manageable, but I find it difficult to handle both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prove that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}] = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}]$.

Then recall that, if $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then $F[x]/ \langle f(x) \rangle \cong F[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$.  In other words, you need to find an irreducible $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$ as a root.

---

Vaguely relevant here is the [primitive element thereom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem), which implies that every field extension $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite degree can be expressed in the form $\mathbb{Q}[a]$ for some $a \in K$.

Comment: Ah, that helps.